# /// <reference types= "cypress" /> not enabling intellisense in VS code

Tags: intellisense, cypress

I'm having a problem trying to get code completion for Cypress while I'm using JS. I've tried following every bit of documentation I could found, but I don't find these comprehensive enough.

Comment: what version of cypress are you on? does the file `node_modules/cypress/types/index.d.ts` exist? does vscode colorize the `/// <reference types="cypress"/>` line? or is it all one color?

Comment: Hi @bkucera, the /// <reference types="cypress"/> is colorized, and I am not able to find the node_modules/cypress/types/index.d.ts. What is this file supposed to contain? Sorry for the noob question, I am really new to this. Regards

Comment: What version of Cypress?

Comment: Did you install via NPM?

Comment: Version 3.1.5, I installed it via the .exe file.

Answer (score 5):

None of these worked for me, what finally gave me Intellisense was adding a `tsconfig.json` file to the Cypress folder, as per the Cypress docs:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": "../node_modules",
    "types": ["cypress"]
  },
  "include": ["**/*.*"]
}
```

Comment: Link to relevant docs: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support#Configure-tsconfig-json

Comment: Yep.  In fact, using `files` in the `cypress/tsconfig.json` might also give you trouble.  Have to use `include/exclude` .  Wierd, and hard to figure out.

Answer (score 3):

I just added

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["cypress"]
  }
```

to the object in the tsconfig.json file that was in the root cypress directory. I then chose "Restart TS Server" from the Command Palette and that sorted things out for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you installed Cypress via the `.exe`, which is not the recommended way of installing Cypress.

Cypress type definitions are only installed when you install cypress via `npm`

For VSCode to find the type definitions,
you should install cypress as a dev dependency to your project (preferred form of installation according to the docs):

```sh
npm i -D cypress
```

Comment: Hi, I've installed it with npm i -g cypress and I get the same "/// <reference types="cypress"/>" colorized. Is there something else I might be overlooking? Thanks!

Comment: It&#39;s more difficult for vscode to pick up global types, so you might have to install locally `npm i -D cypress`

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I was able to set it on vs code by simple adding /// 
I've written it previously with C from Cyberpress in lower case, after adding the C in upper case it solved my problem

Answer (score -2):

### How I get Cypress typings to work in vscode

I had problems getting Cypress intellisense to work too. My way to get intellisense is convoluted and probably wrong, but I didn't get it to work in any other way.

1. add a `cypress.d.ts` file in the root of my project with the following types syntax. This declare the `cy` type, so you get autocompletion for most Cypress stuff:

```
declare var Cypress: any;

interface CypressElement {
  type(value: string, options?: any): CypressElement,
  clear(options?: {force: boolean}): CypressElement,
  click(options?: {force: boolean}): CypressElement,
  should(...args: any): CypressElement,
  selectValue(option: number, optionsClass: string):CypressElement,
  fillInput(value: string):CypressElement,
  eq(index: number): CypressElement,
  contains(value: any): CypressElement,
  within(...args: any): any,
  trigger(...args: any): any;
  first(): CypressElement;
}

declare var cy: {
  get(select: any): CypressElement;
  window(): Promise<any>;
  visit(path: any): void;
  request(options: any): Promise<any>;
  wait(time: string | number): any;
  server(): any;
  route(...options: any): any;
  log(...messages: string[]): any;
  contains(selector: string, value: any): any;
  stub(...args: any): any;
  on(event: string, callback: any): any;
  url(): CypressElement;
};
```

(Declare Cypress typings manually this way seems alien at best. However, trying to use the native ones generated a lot of problems)

2. Reference that file in the `tsconf.json` compiler options via:

   "typeRoots": ["cypress.d.ts"],

This just enables intellisense to Cypress, even if the cypress code is written in javaScript, since vscode relies a lot in typescript for its intellisense engine.

Since you're not using typeScript I guess, you may need to add a very simple `tsconfig` file at the root (so your editor can read its configuration), something like:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "typeRoots": ["cypress.d.ts"],
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": [
            "es6"
        ],
        "declaration": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "stripInternal": true,
        // since 2.3
        // "strict": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true
    },
    "files": [
        "./index.ts"
    ]
}
```

Maybe you can instruct your editor to load `cypress.d.ts` as `typeRoots`, I don't know.

After this, you should have intellisense for your `cy` variable and for the objets that comes from `cy.get()` (which above are called `CypressElement` in that types definition).

One big caveat about this, is that whenever you use a new Cypress feature, you need to manually add its type to `cypress.d.ts` to get the intellisense.

Comment: You sir, you saved me! This works! Thank you very much!

Comment: this doesn't seem like a sensible solution; maintaining your own type definitions is much more difficult than properly pointing your editor to the correct ones

Comment: That is what I say in the first line of the answer :-). I think this is better than not having intellisense at all.

Comment: This is not the way.  Proper config of tsconfig.json files will solve this better, although it is a bit tricksy.